# make a variable into an object have a property?

Tags: javascript

What i want to do is something like this:

```
var num = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
```

so assuming num results to 3, I want to add a method on it and invoke it something like

```
num.lighten()
```

but num must be 3, I thought of something like this:

```
var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 3)
    randomNum = { lighten: () => "hello world" } // it gets override
```

Or something like this, assign a method on random generated number:

```
var  Math.round(Math.random() * 3) = { lighten: () => "hello world" }
```

I wanted to referrence to it as

```
3.lighten()
```

Comment: what would you like to get with `3.lighten()`?

Comment: @NinaScholz change some style with jquery

Comment: please add an example.

Comment: thanks, the answer does the job for me @NinaScholz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this by using a `Number` object:

```js
var num = new Number(Math.round(Math.random() * 3));
num.lighten = function() {
    console.log("hello world, my value is " + this);
};
num.lighten();
var numPlus3 = num + 3;
console.log("num plus 3 is " + numPlus3);
```

Note that `num` is now an object, not a primitive number. But if you use it in a calculation, the primitive value will be used.

If you wanted to do it for **all** numbers, everywhere, you could add a `lighten` function to `Number.prototype`. It's often discouraged to add functions to prototypes because of the risk of collision, so I wouldn't do it in a library at all and would think very hard before doing it in an app. But this is what that would look like:

```js
// Once, in your init
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, "lighten", {
  value: function() {
    console.log("hello world, my value is " + this);
  }
});

// Example of use
var num = new Number(Math.round(Math.random() * 3));
num.lighten();
```

But again, think hard before extending built-in prototypes. If you do:

- Never do it in library code you'll be sharing with others
- Only add non-enumerable properties (by using `Object.defineProperty`)
- Be aware of the possibility of conflict with features added later as JavaScript's standard library evolves